# How to play animations with staggered start times in manim

Tags: python, manim

I'm just learning manim and I'm trying to play a bunch of animations that have overlapping start and end times.

Suppose T is the length of time it takes each FadeIn to play. What I want is for them to start and finish in a staggered manner, e.g. the first animation starts at 0, the second starts at T/10, the third at 2T/10, ... , the 10th starts at 9T/10, and then the first one finishes at T, the second finishes at 11T/10, the third finishes at 12T/10, ..., the 10th finishes at 19T/10.

I know how to play animations one after another or in parallel like this, but neither of these has staggered start times:

```
from manim import *


class FadeInAllAtOnce(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        circles = [Circle(r / 10) for r in range(10)]
        anims = [FadeIn(c) for c in circles]
        self.play(*anims)


class FadeInOneAfterAnother(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        circles = [Circle(r / 10) for r in range(10)]
        anims = [FadeIn(c) for c in circles]
        for anim in anims:
            self.play(anim)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a probably-good-enough solution, [LaggedStart (little documentation)](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.animation.composition.LaggedStart.html#manim.animation.composition.LaggedStart), which will play a bunch of animations one after another with a configurable lag given by the lag_ratio (default = .05) parameter.

```
from manim import *


class FadeInStaggeredMap(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        circles = [Circle(r / 10) for r in range(10)]
        anims = [FadeIn(c) for c in circles]
        self.play(LaggedStart(*anims))
```

Comment: Is it possible to have non-uniform or unequal time lags between successive animations?